# How to add weather layer to the current infowindow Google Map?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geolocation, google-weather-api

I want to add this forecast to the infowindow. I wanna use Google weather layers. But i dont know how to put them to the current infowindow

```
var weatherLayer = new google.maps.weather.WeatherLayer({
temperatureUnits: google.maps.weather.TemperatureUnit.FAHRENHEIT
});
var cloudLayer = new google.maps.weather.CloudLayer();
```

How can i add forecast to the current info window, after details of location?

Thank you

```
function showPosition(position) {
    var googlePos = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 12,
        center: googlePos,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    var mapObj = document.getElementById('divmap');
    var googleMap = new google.maps.Map(mapObj, mapOptions);

    var markerOpt = {
        map: googleMap,
        position: googlePos,
        title: 'Hi , I am here',
        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
    };

    var googleMarker = new google.maps.Marker(markerOpt);
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    geocoder.geocode({
        'latLng': googlePos
    }, function (results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            if (results[1]) {
                var popOpts = {
                    content: results[1].formatted_address,
                    position: googlePos
                };
                var popup = new google.maps.InfoWindow(popOpts);
                /*google.maps.event.addListener(googleMap, 'center_changed', function(){
                                    window.setTimeout(function(){
                                        googleMap.panTo(googleMarker.getPosition());
                                    }, 2000);

                                });*/

                google.maps.event.addListener(googleMarker, 'setTimeout', setTimeout(function () {
                    popup.open(googleMap, googleMarker)
                }, 200));
            } else {
                alert('No results found');
            }
        } else {
            alert('Geocoder failed due to: ' + status);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: 1) The Weather library has been deprecated so you should not start developing with it. 2) Create the infowindow object with a global scope and use the `setContent` method to change its content.

Comment: so what can you recommend for using to add forecast for current location?

Comment: Find another API. There are plenty of them: http://openweathermap.org/api http://www.wunderground.com/weather/api/ https://api.accuweather.com/ etc. Just google *weather api*.